# strtoXX : check overflow

Tags: c

As we know, strtoXX functions return max(or min) value if overflow occur, for example, `strtoul("999999999999999999999999999999999", NULL, 0)` returns `ULONG_MAX`. But `strtoul("0xffffffff", NULL, 0)` returns also `ULONG_MAX`(if sizeof(unsigned long) == 4).

Then, how can I check overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/

> If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an
>   unsigned long int, the function returns ULONG_MAX (defined in
>   ), and errno is set to ERANGE.

You're dealing with unsigned integers, so it doesn't matter what sign your integer has: they're all treated as unsigned integers. And 0xFF FF FF FF (assuming 4 bytes as you're doing) is negative, but it's being treated as +4294967295 (not 2's complement). And that's also exactly the value of `ULONG_MAX` in that case.

Comment: So checking errno is enough?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: you should set `errno` to `0` before calling `strtoul()` to make sure that it wasn't set to `ERANGE` somewhere earlier in the program (standard library functions do not set `errno` to `0` on success).

Comment: In this particular case (0xFF FF FF FF) errno is not even set since it is not overflow (it is just converting the maximum to ULONG_MAX). No clamping happens

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is *not* negative, numeric literals in C never are. If this number doesn't fit into a positive `int` is is of type `unsigned`.

Comment: It is not, but I think OP was referring to treating it as a signed 4-bytes integer.